# problem in attachments when send email with TransportBuilder

Tags: magento2

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

i have problem in attachments when send email with TransportBuilder

Comment: Please add some context.
What is the problem ? Do you have an error ? Which version are you using ? Is it a custom module ? What is the path ?

Comment: I have an error in attachment when sends mail, the name of attachment "income" and don't have extensions, I use Magento 2.2.9 and it is a custom module